# Google Sheets Dropdown "Input must fall within specified range". How to solve this?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a very simple Dropdown on Google Sheets that is working perfectly.
Basically when I select an item from the dropdown, it will output that same item on another cell.

**Works with dropdown items (see image)**
[image: Works with dropdown items (see image)]

However, I also want to write a custom text (that is not available in the dropdown) to be outputed.

Here's what I mean exactly:

**Not working when entering a custom text (see image)**
[image: Not working when entering a custom text (see image)]

But I'm getting an error.

Is there a code that if you enter a text that is not in the specified range, it would display the text without an error?

Comment: I think you could do it with an onEdit() but could explain further what mean by `if you enter a text that is not in the specified range` I'm not sure what you mean by specified range

Comment: Basically when you create a dropdown, you have an option from where to display dropdown items.

Using Data>Data Validation, you can select a cell specified range where your list is located. For example: =$A$1:$A$5

Then I can output the dropdown results on a completely different cell using this formula:

=VLOOKUP(B1,A1:A5,1,FALSE)

This works great.

Here's a live example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13EWNcqx1QDlmNP1Pv9OVQcmSoGZtkU3ihNAIJVQsW3M/edit?usp=sharing

But I also want to manually enter a text that's not in the dropdown list to output as a result.

Comment: Then it would be best to leave blank locations in the range and put you new additions into those blank locations.  By default the dropdown will not display blank cells in that specified range.

Comment: Solved it using =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B1,A1:A5,1,FALSE),D1)  

Basically when an error occurs, it will take info from cell D1.

This is where I can now enter my manual text to be outputed in the same cell as dropdown result.